# Error: The type or namespace name 'MVC' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore'

Tags: configuration, site-configuration

I'm facing this issue in one of my testing instances:

**Sitecore 9.1.0**

```
Inner Exception: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\84f876eb\34615233\App_Web_events.cshtml.9351e6fa.fnj8_tct.0.cs(27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MVC' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

And I'm starting to get out of ideas.

Do you guys what should I be looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your project reference Sitecore.Mvc.dll? Correct version of that dll? Is your project `Target framework` property set to `.NET Framework 4.7.1`?

Comment: Namespaces are case sensitive? It should be `Mvc` not `MVC`. At least that's worth trying out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add Sitecore.Mvc namespace inside views/web.config file, like:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>        
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Also, make sure that Sitecore.Mvc.dll in your root folder is from the correct version. To confirm, just try to copy the dll from a vanilla sitecore instance into your bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

Pro tip guys, never underestimate the **power of case sensitiveness**.

When adding the references on *views/web.config*, make sure you do this:

```
<add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />
```

Instead of this:

```
<add namespace="Sitecore.MVC" />
```

That fixed my problem.